# .bind method in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to bind a click event to a div which contains a input button. What i want is when the button is clicked i want to call another function.

The HTML div class is shown below.

```
var searchAttachPoint= document.querySelector('.header1');
```

And in my javascript i have these lines.

```
var searchAttachPoint= document.querySelector('.header1');
$(#header1).bind("click",searchPrompt("Key the text and press Ok", false));
```

I am getting an error saying "Unexpected token ILLEGAL " in the line where i bing the click event. Could someone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just in case fixing this causes another problem, `searchPrompt` will need to return a function for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite positive you want to do:

```
$("#header1").bind('click', function () {
    searchPrompt("Key the text and press Ok", false);
});
```

You should also use `.on` over `.bind` if it's available.

You also don't use the `searchAttachPoint` from your example.  Note that `.header1` and `#header` are different, so maybe you even mean to do `$(searchAttachPoint).bind`, but that's not necessary when `$(".header1")` would work.

Answer (score 3):

`$(#header1)` should be `$('#header1')`